# Convert CassandraRow to JSON form string in scala

Tags: json, scala, cassandra

I have this string:

```
CassandraRow{
    email: test@example.com,
    lastname: Example,
    name: User,
    password: Password}
```

How can I convert the above string in the form of JSON string of type?

```
{"email": "test@example.com",
 "lastname": "Example",
 "name": "User",
 "password": "Password"}
```

Comment: Have you considered: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom?

Comment: Is it possible without using external api?

Comment: Are you using Datastax Java driver? It's possible, just really ugly.

Comment: No i am not using Datastax Java Driver. It's fine if its ugly, can you please share it.

Comment: What's the json lib?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you. which Json lib are you talking about?

Comment: @Anonymous What driver are you using then?

Comment: I am not sure about the best JSON lib for Spark but Json4s is an option.


```import org.json4s.native.Serialization.{read, write, writePretty}
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
val json =  write(cassandraRowObject)
val a = read[CassandraRow](json)```

Comment: Thanks everyone I did this by using a case class

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataAsString method to extract whatever is inside the CassandraRow and then it's much easier to work on it.